# Remove space after number occurrence in 'label' column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with 'label' column which has poor punctuation and spacing values. After cleaning the punctuation using string replace now need to delete space after the number occurrence.

Below is df with sample values:

```
label = {'label':['L1 RE','L1 REL3 RE', 'Quality','L1 RE L3 Algo', 'PM, L4 HW,L1 SW'],
        'name':['mon','tue','wed','thur','fri']}
df = pd.DataFrame(label)
```

I tried regex: `number = re.search(r'\d+', df['label']).group()`

But get error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: So, do you want to remove all spaces in `Label`? `df['label'].str.replace(' ','')`? `df['label'].str.replace(r'(\d)\s+',r'\1')`?

Comment: I want to remove space after the digit occurrence and replace from above helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df['label'] = df['label'].str.replace(r'(\d)\s+',r'\1')
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/61qYE5/1).

In this case, a digit is matched *and captured* with `(\d)` and one or more whitespace chars are just matched, and since the replacement is a backreference to the Group 1 value, the whitespaces are removed as a result of the `Series.str.replace`.

Full Pandas test:

```
import pandas as pd
label = {'label':['L1 RE','L1 REL3 RE', 'Quality','L1 RE L3 Algo', 'PM, L4 HW,L1 SW'], 'name':['mon','tue','wed','thur','fri']}
df = pd.DataFrame(label)
df['label'] = df['label'].str.replace(r'(\d)\s+',r'\1')
>>> df
           label  name
0           L1RE   mon
1       L1REL3RE   tue
2        Quality   wed
3    L1RE L3Algo  thur
4  PM, L4HW,L1SW   fri
```